# How to convert List<Object> to Map<String , List<String>> using java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have Employee object which has rowId, skillId and student as below

```
[0, 20,"John"],

[1, 30,"Amy"],

[2, 20,"Tom"]
```

and I need response like this:

```
Map<skillId, List<student>>

20 , ["John","Tom"]

30 , [Amy]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSkillId,Collectors.mapping(Employee:getStudent,Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `groupingBy` and `mapping`

```
list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSkillId,
                    Collectors.mapping(Employee:getStudent, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: it is working but 1 issue as it is returning map<skillid, List<user>>  but my method returns map<String, List<String>>  
Map<String, List<String>> skillAndList = new HashMap<>();   
skillAndList = employeeList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSkillSet,
                 Collectors.mapping(Employee::getUser, Collectors.toList())));
so it is not compatable to assign the response to skillAndList

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below,

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> collect = employeeList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSkillId, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> skillAndList = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSkillId, Collectors.mapping(Employee::getStudent, Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(skillAndList);
```

The output is the same as you expected -

```
{30=[Amy], 20=[John,Tom]}
```